# Detect the button was clicked and make it invisible

Tags: android, button, visible

I have the following method which I want for few buttons to show the image and for the rest of the buttons should be invisible when clicked. Whatever the other v.getId() is I want it to be invisible.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.d){
                imgD.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.i){
                imgI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(v.getId() == R.id.l){
                imgL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                //if other buttons are clicked then the button must be invisible.
            }
        }
```

Comment: did u tired gone property?

Comment: please explain properly i cann't under stand?

Comment: or chat on this link i wil help u properly  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/522/android-for-life

Answer (score 1):

For invisibilty, there is method in android,

```
imgD.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Let me know is it working or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `View.GONE`

```
  yourview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

`public static final int GONE`

Added in API level 1

This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.

If you use `INVISIBLE` the view is invisible but takes up the layout space.

Comment: @ivesingh what are you trying to suggest that the above won't work?

Comment: @ivesingh if other buttons are clicked then the button must be invisible. can you pls elaborate this

Answer (score 0):

try

```
else{
    yourButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);// it will take the space in layout
     //or
     yourButton.setVisibility(View.GONNE);// it will not take  the space in layout

    }
```